# How to show a read-only variable in the Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Weapon",  menuName = "Item/Weapon")]
public class WeaponItemSprite : ItemTypeScriptableObject
{
    public GameObject gameObject;
    public Sprite sprite;
    public string weaponName = "Weapon name";
    public Rarity rarity = Rarity.Normal;
    public ItemType itemType = ItemType.Weapon;
    [Range(0f, 1000f)]
    public float damage = 1f;
    [Range(0f, 20f)]
    public int cost = 1;
}
```

[image]

I want it so that `Item.type` will be shown in the Inspector and be "greyed out" and you cannot change it.

Comment: If it is not changeable why show it at all? You can always see it anyway via the Debug mode

Comment: There exists an [open source asset](https://github.com/dbrizov/NaughtyAttributes) that provides a handy list of attributes, including showing non-serialized and read-only values.

Answer (score 1):

I use these small snippets of code, and it works like a charm.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class ReadOnlyAttribute : PropertyAttribute { }
```

Put this specific script in the `Editor` folder

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

// Put this script in the "Editor" folder
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute))]
public class ReadOnlyDrawer : PropertyDrawer {

    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        return EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(property, label, true);
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {

        GUI.enabled = false;
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, label, true);
        GUI.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Then you can mark any variable that needs to be greyed out with the attribute as `[ReadOnly]` and it won't be editable in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [custom Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) or [PropertyDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) for this using e.g. [`EditorGUI.DisabledGroupScope`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.DisabledGroupScope.html) or if going for UIElements [`VisualElement.SetEnabled(false)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.VisualElement.SetEnabled.html)

There are assets that already implement handy decorator drawers like e.g. [NaughtyAtttributes](https://github.com/dbrizov/NaughtyAttributes)

---

As a complete alternative approach - assuming that this "field" is actually to be implemented by all inheritors of `ItemTypeScriptableObject` anyway - you could rather use a property

```
public abstract class ItemTypeScriptableObject : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract ItemType itemType { get; }
}
```

and then inheritors can still decide whether they want to expose it

```
[field: SerilaizeField]
public override ItemType itemType { get; private set; }
```

or - like in your case - have a fixed value (not visible in the Inspector, though)

```
public override ItemType itemType => ItemType.Weapon;
```

Comment: Thank you. Not simple as just add [SerialzedField] or something like that, bit it is  what it is.

Comment: @serjeq_unity as said people already did this in e.g. NaughtyAttributes where you can simply do `[ReadOnly]`